# Node.js stream pipes and garbage collection

Tags: node.js, stream, garbage-collection, pipe

**Question:**
In Node.js, if a Readable stream is piped to a Writable stream and both go out of scope, is the pair of streams liable to be garbage collected before the reader is complete? (because they are now inaccessible)

**Background:**
I am trying to understand the effects of pipes on stream object lifetimes.  I am operating under the assumption that a pipe represents a bidirectional reference between the two streams, so that if one is accessible, neither will be garbage collected (until, of course, the reader ends and the pipe is closed).

So with that assumption: Is there anything under the hood in the runtime that holds streams in existence while a pipe is active, or while a 'data' listener on the Readable is doing the equivalent?  (apart from the obvious, like references embedded in event listener functions and other objects)

A concrete example would be piping a file read stream to an http response object.  If I "pipe-and-forget", and retain no reference to the file or response stream, is this process liable to be interrupted mid-stream?

Or alternatively, if something is holding off the GC for piped streams, would a bidirectional pipe between two sockets exist indefinitely, even if they were both inaccessible? (and be totally unclosable?)

Comment: My thinking is that it depends on the kind of stream. If you are working with a garden-variety readable/writable streams whose source and sink are in memory, then I would imagine that they could be GC-ed at any time if there are no refs to them. However, streams dealing with OS resources may behave differently and may stick around. (I am not certain of this, so this is a comment, not an answer.) Regardless of the behavior, I'd say it's bad form to pipe and forget since that would make it harder to do error handling, testing, and other good things.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but if you look at the general tutorial example of an http file server, they generally pipe and then let both streams go out of scope.  Also, even a garden-variety general stream may be a transform stream that is in the middle of a chained pipe from one OS-resource stream to another, (e.g. read a file, pipe through my transform, send to http response), so a pipe must be able to prevent GC if the process is going to succeed.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: You may be right. I don't have much confidence in what I am saying right now. :) But I also haven't seen anything with a clear explanation. Looking forward to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, as usual, is: it depends.

If nothing references the stream objects then they will be garbage collected. However, there might be references elsewhere than in your code.

Note that the writable stream is referenced by the readable stream via event handlers, so all we really need is a reference to the readable stream to keep both alive.

If the source is a stream that is capable of producing data all by itself (it reads from a file, the network, or something in memory) *and* the pipeline is flowing, then it *will* be referenced by a callback somewhere (an I/O continuation, event handler, or closure given to `setTimeout()` or `process.nextTick()`).

If the source is a stream that is waiting for you to push data into it or the pipeline is paused, then there are likely no references and both streams will eventually be garbage-collected.